# Sum over unix timestamps in grafana prometheus

Tags: gpu, devops, prometheus, grafana, promql

Lets say I have `my_val` for a value in prometheus, that is recorded when I use a gpu instance. I want to sum up how many hours or gpu usage I had in the past week. I can call `timestamp(myval{instance="$instance"})` which will return a vector with timestamps, but I cannot call `sum(idelta)` over them because it is an instant vector for some reason.

Grafana also messes with the amount of data requested based on how far I am zooming.

How do I create a reliable call for every datapoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
count_over_time(my_val[7d]) * <scrape_interval> / 3600
```

Where `<scrape_interval>` is scrape interval in seconds set in Prometheus config file for the target that exports `my_val` metric.
This query assumes that `my_val` doesn't contain data points when gpu instance wasn't used.